# OutputStream is not available when a custom TextWriter is used mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, charts

Im trying to get a chart on my view and I´m displaying it like this in my view:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h2>ChartResult</h2>

<% using (Html.BeginForm("HandleChartType", "Chart")) %>
<% { %>

    <%= Html.DropDownList("ListItems", "Select Chart Type")%>

    <input type="submit" value="Set Chart" />
 <%} %>




<% myChart.Controls.Add(ViewData["Chart"] as Chart);  %>  
<asp:Panel ID="myChart" runat="server"></asp:Panel>



<!--<img src="/Chart/CreateChart" alt="" />-->


<h2>FormResults</h2>

</asp:Content>
```

This line <% myChart.Controls.Add(ViewData["Chart"] as Chart);  %> generates the error message OutputStream is not available when a custom TextWriter is used

This is the code from the controller:

```
    public ActionResult ChartResult()
    {

        List<string> items = GetFilteredChartTypes();
        ViewData["ListItems"] = new SelectList(items);

        Chart myChart = CreateChart(SeriesChartType.Column);
        ViewData["Chart"] = myChart;

        return View();
    }
```

The CreateChart function just creates a chart with Column as chart type.
Why do I get this error, OutputStream is not available when a custom TextWriter is used?

Comment: possible duplicate of [BinaryWrite exception "OutputStream is not available when a custom TextWriter is used" in MVC 2 ASP.NET 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261198/binarywrite-exception-outputstream-is-not-available-when-a-custom-textwriter-is)

Comment: Why you use MVC view like a WebForms page?

Answer (score 0):

I think that problem is in wrong approach.
When building charts you have two options.

One way is to generate chart **image** and then your view will consist of `<img />` tag with `src` attribute set to url of controller/action which generates chart image.

Another way is to build controller with JSON action, which returns chart **data only**. This is more flexible way because you'll get freedom to choose any of ready-to-go javascript libraries that visualize charts (html5 canvas or svg)